# Cover a square with three smaller squares

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, geometry

A square has a side length of 5 units. Is it possible to cover this square with three squares each with a side length of 4 units?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> yes

> see picture red is 5x5 the other three are 4x4
>  [image]
>
>  few measurements on the green square: the triangle outside the red square to the left has sides $4,3,5$, therefore the triangle outside the red to the top has sides $1,0.75,1.25$ the crucial thing being $1.25 \ge 5-4$

Comment: Your diagram looks stretched; none of the squares look square.

Comment: @user3294068 If you rotate the screen about 55 degrees to one side, then they all do.

Answer (score 5):

> This is a known problem.

> The answer is “yes”.

> Because the golden ratio $\varphi=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}=1.618\dots$  is bigger than $\left(\frac 54\right)^2=1.44$

> The following cover of a square of area $\varphi$ by three unit squares
>  was found by Henry E. Dudeney in 1931.

> [image]

> Erich Friedman had a page “[Squares Covering Squares](https://web.archive.org/web/20171030160239/https://www2.stetson.edu/%7Eefriedma/squcosqu/)” with coverings of the largest known square by $n$ unit squares.

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is

> no.

Explanation:

- First place one of the $4\times4$ squares within the $5\times5$ square. The remaining area (9 units) should be as compact as possible, so let's shift the $4\times4$ square right up to one corner, leaving an L-shape remaining. (I'm not sure how to prove rigorously that this is optimal.)
- Now we need to place the other two squares so as to cover that L-shape. Surely the best way to do this is

  > diagonally, so that the longest possible part of the $4\times4$ square is along the length of the L on each side.

It seems this should be enough to cover the $5\times5$ square, since

> $4\sqrt{2}>5$,

but actually it's not that easy,

> because the total $4\sqrt{2}$ length only covers zero width when the square is placed diagonally.

Let's do a quick bit of calculation:

> [image: calculation]
>
>  Placed diagonally inside the $4\times4$ square for maximum length, the longest width-$1$ box that can fit is of length $4\sqrt{2}-1=4.66$.
>
>  Even allowing for the fact that the two additional $4\times4$ squares will meet at the corner of the L-shape, there's no way we can cover all of the two open edges of the $5\times5$ square, since our coverage of them will only go as far as $4.66$ along before the coverage starts to slope away from the edge.

Comment: Good effort undone by one little inaccuracy (_"Surely the best way to do this is "_), still +1

Comment: Ouch, I feel for Rand. Keep answering puzzles! And welcome Paul, I see you answered a lot recently.

Comment: Certainly not "rigorous" either, but definitely seems likely that you need to go to a corner because otherwise you will have to cover areas on both sides of the smaller square. With only 3 squares to work with (2 remaining besides the first one not on a corner in this scenario), that seems really hard to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cover the four corners, so one of the smaller squares covers two corners of the bigger one and the other two smalls cover one corner each.

Comment: How can you cover two corners of the bigger square using one of the smaller squares?

Comment: Turn it 45 degrees and make each of the two adjacent top edges coincident with one of the top vertices of the bigger square.